# Accessing XBMC on a computer withssh server

Tags: networking, ssh, xbmc

I have XBMC installed on an Ubuntu computer (as a program, not "Kodibuntu"). The Android remote app  for XBMC is not able to connect to the server even after I disable the firewall. I suspect this is because an ssh server is running on the computer and it requires a password or a key file for authentication. What can I do?

Comment: Did you allow remote control in Kodi settings?

Comment: Yes, I have done so.